# Will my old film lenses be damaged if they are exposed to high temperatures in a moving truck?

Tags: lens, old-lenses, environmental-dangers, heat

I’m moving cross country and am slightly worried about some of my film camera lenses and bodies in the heat.

The moving company said it’s possible for the trucks to get between 105F-120F. I’m worried this can cause haze in the old film lenses, is this a legitimate concern? Should I move the cameras separate from the rest of my things?

Comment: How much gear are you moving?  How are you moving yourself?

Comment: two bags, ~7-10bodies, ~10-15 lenses. I’m being flown out and bringing body and ~5 lenses with me. But I don’t have much room for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

120F is the temperature of a good ol' summer day in Phoenix, Arizona, USA. People have been shooting there for decades with film to no detriment. That being said, it's still considered an "extreme" temperature by some and the higher temps are sure to not be as kind to your gear as a temperate climate. I know my gear - I know how old it is, how it's been used, signs of haze already there, and I know whether I'd use it in hot (hot and humid/dusty) weather (the answer is yes<sup>1</sup>).

But, I don't know your gear and really can't advise one way or the other. Even if someone on the internet told you it'd be perfectly fine, I think you'd still be concerned. So, it's a small price to pay to ship your gear UPS/FedEx/USPS Priority and have some peace of mind.

---

<sub>1: I'm also the kind of person that thinks a camera is a tool. Yes, I love my gear - but I also love taking photos and am very often in really crap conditions. I know I may kill a lens or body to get the shot. If you're a fair-weather photographer, Pelican case your gear and ship it speedy for the peace of mind.</sub>